# How to remove empty tags from local xml file using python

Tags: python, xml

I am generating one xml file but it contains empty tags.
I need to remove those tags in program before reading the contents of that file.

This is how my xml file looks like in XML image:
[image]

The code I am writing is :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 


# parse an xml file by name

#file = ET.parse(r"C:\Users\hu170f\Documents\TEST\myData4.xml")

tree = ET.parse(r'C:\Users\hu170f\Documents\TEST\myData5.xml')
root = tree.getroot()  
print(root)
```

This code is working fine in another xml which does not contain empty tags.

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\hu170f\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2963, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-166-8f7c8e1443ce>", line 8, in <module>
    tree = ET.parse(r'C:\Users\hu170f\Documents\TEST\myData5.xml')

  File "C:\Users\hu170f\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1196, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)

  File "C:\Users\hu170f\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 597, in parse
    self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)

  File "<string>", line unknown
ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 9, column 5
```

How do I correct this issue?

My XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"   encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<MCD>
    <Field>Value</Field>
    <File_Name>MAAP-S12_LH_UP_PASS-LN1-V1.csv</File_Name>
    <Source_File_Name></Source_File_Name>
    <Time_Stamp></Time_Stamp>
    <Part>LH_UP_PASS</Part>
    <Machine>S12_Trim+Drill</Machine>
    <></>
    <></>
    <name>Setup_1</name>
    <time>4</time>
    <Primary_Spindle>1</Primary_Spindle>
    <></>
    <name>Trim_LE</name>
    <time>4</time>
    <Primary_Spindle>1</Primary_Spindle>
    <></>
    <name>Trim_TE</name>
    <time>4</time>
    <Primary_Spindle>1</Primary_Spindle>
    <></>
    <name>Drill1</name>
    <time>4</time>
    <Primary_Spindle>1</Primary_Spindle>
    <></>
    <name>Drill_2</name>
    <time>4</time>
    <Primary_Spindle>1</Primary_Spindle>
    <></>
    <name>Drill_3</name>
    <time>4</time>
    <Primary_Spindle>1</Primary_Spindle>
    <></>
    <></>
    <name>Drill_4</name>
    <time>4</time>
    <Primary_Spindle>2</Primary_Spindle>
    <></>
    <name>Drill_5</name>
    <time>4</time>
    <Primary_Spindle>2</Primary_Spindle>
    <></>
    <name>Drill_6</name>
    <time>4</time>
    <Primary_Spindle>2</Primary_Spindle>
    <></>
    <name>Hole_Probe</name>
    <time>4</time>
    <Tolerance>0.02</Tolerance>
    <Primary_Spindle>2</Primary_Spindle>
    <></>
    <name>End</name>
    <time>0</time>
    <Secondary_Spindle>All</Secondary_Spindle>
</MCD>
enter code here
```

Comment: Upload the xml as text please.

Answer (score 0):

A XML parser will not work for that, since your file is not a XML file (empty tags don't exist in XML). That's the meaning of your error message. If all your tags are as you've shown in the picture, you may simply open the file as text and remove those entries:

```py
clean_lines = []
with open('xml_file.xml', 'r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        clean_lines.append(line.replace('<>', '').replace('</>', ''))

# Now save the file:
with open('clean_xml_file.xml', 'w') as fh:
    for line in clean_lines:
        fh.write(line)
```

Just change the name of the files before and after cleaning to something that works for you. If the files are too large to hold in memory, you can interleave reading and writing (as long as the files are different), like this:

```py
with open('xml_file.xml', 'r') as in_fh:
    with open('clean_xml_file.xml', 'w') as out_fh:
        for line in in_fh:
            out_fh.write(line.replace('<>', '').replace('</>', ''))
```